# How do I teleport a player to a Part when a ProximityPrompt is triggered?

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I have been trying to make a game with multiple enemies. Now, those enemies, they are caged in a cage far from the Baseplate. I made a ProximityPrompt inside a part which is transparent and have CanCollide off which if triggered will teleport you to the position of another transparent part which is inside the cage. I have been researching on how to do this. I put this code on a LocalScript in the ProximityPrompt:

```
local teleportPart = game.Workspace.TELEPORT.Position

script.Parent.Triggered:Connect(function()
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:MoveTo(teleportPart)
end)

-- TELEPORT is the transparent part in the cage.
```

Then, I tested it. However, when the ProximityPrompt is triggered, nothing happens. No errors in the command bar, nothing.

I tried multiple ways such as:

1. Change `game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:MoveTo(teleportPart)` to `Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(2350.5, -6.2, 639.015)`
2. Making the teleportPart said immediately, (sorry I couldn't think of a word for it) example: `game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:MoveTo(game.Workspace.TELEPORT.Postion)`
3. Placing the "Postion" in "MoveTo" and deleting it from the variable. (`game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:MoveTo(teleportPart.Postion)`)

None have worked, none have errors. What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code and all of your previous attempts look fine, but your issue is that [LocalScripts](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/LocalScript) only execute from a handful of locations. According to the documentation :

> A LocalScript will only run Lua code if it is a descendant of one of the following objects:
>
> - A Player's Backpack, such as a child of a Tool,
> - A Player's character model,
> - A Player's PlayerGui,
> - A Player's PlayerScripts,
> - The ReplicatedFirst service.

Since your LocalScript is the child of a ProximityPrompt in the Workspace, it simply never executes.

So to fix your issue, convert your LocalScript to a Script and try this. You can get the Player who activated the prompt as an argument from the [Triggered](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/ProximityPrompt#Triggered) event :

```lua
local proximityPrompt = script.Parent
local teleportPart = game.Workspace.TELEPORT

proximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    local character = player.Character
    if character then
        character:MoveTo(teleportPart.Position)
    end
end)
```